# 256 Colors in xterm and tmux [in FreeBSD 10]

Tags: colors, xterm, terminal-emulator, urxvt, sakura

So these past few days I am working to make Xterm and tmux show all the 256 colors available in them by default. I reach these conclusions:

- for tmux to show 256 colors you have to make xterm to show it.
- `export TERM=xterm-256color` in `~/.bashrc` make xterm to show all 256 color. but this is problematic; when you do that you set the whole terminal to xterm and even urxvt will report back its **$TERM** as Xterm not `rxvt-unicode-256color`.

So I am looking for the way to just target the xterm. and leave other terminal emulators alone.

PS: I had the same problem ith Urxvt but I solved it by tweaking its Makefile and removed `--with-rxvt`

Answer (score 4):

To do this specifically for `xterm`, add the following line to your `~/.Xresources` file:

```
xterm*termName: xterm-256color
```

The reload your `.Xresources` with:

```
xrdb ~/.Xresources
```

Or logout then back in again.

Another option would be to add the following to your `.bashrc` (or equivalent file that will be sourced when your shell starts):

```
[ "$TERM" = xterm ] && export TERM=xterm-256color
```

The only danger with this is that many other terminals that are not actually `xterm` set `TERM` to `xterm`. If you find yourself using one like this that does not support 256 colours, you may have issues.

Comment: First is it `xterm*termName` or `Xterm*termName` and the second what is the .Xresources line for screen (tmux).

Comment: Either `xterm*termName` or `XTerm*termName` work for me. Not `Xterm*termName` though. I don't understand what you mean by 'what is the `.Xresources` line for screen (tmux)?' `screen` and `tmux` are not affected by `.Xresources`.

Comment: thanks I want to know exactly "`screen` and `tmux` are not affected by `.Xresources`."

Comment: Arch has a good [wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_resources) on `.Xresources`. It is really only relevant for applications that use the XWindow system directly (like `xterm`). `tmux` and `screen` are terminal applications and do not use the window system at all. Are you maybe looking for how to make `xterm` start `tmux` or `screen` by default instead of the user's shell (`bash` in most cases).

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
case "$TERM" in
xterm*)
  TERM=xterm-256color;;
rxvt*)
  ;;
*)
  ;;
esac
```

to your `.bashrc`